# Omit last dot character and everything thereafter in VS code snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

My goal is to convert

`my-app/templates/components/one-directory/a-second-directory/third.hbs`

to

`<OneDirectory::ASecondDirectory::Third />`

The following snippet does everything I need it to, except removing the extension, so the above example results in `<OneDirectory::ASecondDirectory::ThirdHbs />`

```
"Path to Angle Bracket": {
    "prefix": "path-to-angle",
    "body": [
      "<${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/.+components\\/|([^\\/]+)|(\\/)/${1:/pascalcase}${2:+::}/g}/>",
    ],
    "description": "Converts a file path to an angle bracket component invocation."
  }
```

I would like to be able to remove the extension without knowing what it is- so essentially remove everything after the final `.` char.

**The regex can be broken down as follows:**

`.+components\\/` - match everything up to and including the first instance of `components/`. Because it is not part of a capture group, it is omitted from the result.

`([^\\/]+)` - first capture group. One or more of any char that is not `/`.

`(\\/)` - second capture group- any `/`

`${1:/pascalcase}` - transform matches of the first capture group to pascal case.

`${2:+::}` - transform matches of the second capture group to `::`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"<${TM_SELECTED_TEXT//.+components\\/|([^(\\/.\\s)]+)|(\\/)|(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}${2:+::}/g} />",
```

See https://regex101.com/r/snLmCK/2

[and thanks for using `:/pascalcase`]

Comment: I made one small modification, to have a single forward slash following TM_SELECTED_TEXT. It worked perfectly with that edit, thank you.